# running multiple multi-route Flask applications

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

I have a flask app script that has multiple routes...

```
#app.py
def create_app(Tractor_id=0):
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/id") 
def start():
    return Tractor_id

@app.route("/stop")
def stop():
```

I'm trying to implement it multiple times with different parameters each time with the help of `DispatcherMiddleware` but I'm having trouble with it.
Here's the actual implementation:

```
# multiapp.py
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

import start

T1 = start.create_app(Tractor_id='101')
T2 = start.create_app(Tractor_id='102')    

# merge
application = DispatcherMiddleware(
    None, {
    '/{}'.format('T101'): T1,
    '/{}'.format('T102'): T2
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple(
        hostname='localhost',
        port=5000,
        application=application,
        use_reloader=True,
        use_debugger=True,
        use_evalex=True)
```

In the *index.html* there are buttons that should redirect the user to the */id* and */stop* routes, but the do not work.

The general question would be, how to run multiple Flask applications which each have multiple routes within them?

Answer (score -2):

I dont know `DispatcherMiddleware`.

But if you are trying to bind few flask servers, just pick for every process **another port** and it will work.
When you request them of course pay attention to port.

If you are struggling with actually making a multi route server, [heres a good example.](http://www.compjour.org/lessons/flask-single-page/multiple-dynamic-routes-in-flask/)